# Go to C# project file from Solution view in Rider

Tags: c#, .net-core, rider, jetbrains-rider

I have a solution which contains many C# projects.

When I open it in Rider and I switch to Solution view, how can I easily go to particular project file (`*.csproj`) or solution file (`*.sln`)?

`JetBrains Rider 2022.2.1`

Comment: Press hotkey F4 ?

Comment: F4 now works for me, but it wasn't at some point. Thanks.

Comment: Then create an issue in jetbrains public issue tracker and attach logs.. you can do it right from IDE: Help -> Report a bug

Answer (score 1):

You could use right click on file -> Edit-> Edit 'file name'. And you will see shortcut in this menu.[image]